# JDBC -- database failure

Tags: google-app-engine, jdbc

I have the following methods that are encountering some sort of failure with my database.  No error is being written to my console, so I'm confused.  I'm using JDBC and Google AppEngine.  Can anyone help me, please?  Thanks.

```
public List<Bulletin> getApprovedBulletins() {
    List<Bulletin> bulletins = new ArrayList<Bulletin>();

    try {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeQuery("select * from bulletins where approved = true");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Bulletin bulletin = new Bulletin();
            bulletin.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            bulletin.setDate(resultSet.getDate("bulletin_date"));
            bulletin.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            bulletin.setSubject(resultSet.getString("subject"));
            bulletin.setNote(resultSet.getString("bulletin"));

            bulletins.add(bulletin);
        }

        resultSet.close();
        connection.close();
        return bulletins;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    return null;
}

private Connection getConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cpc";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  I found a place to print out a message to my console, and it turns out I needed to add the following to appengine-web.xml, which I have done.

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse check the markers tab for errors. Note that the driver must be in the application server folder as well in order to work. Not sure why you don't get any errors in the console though...